# ¿Cómo accedo un contenedor Docker desde otro PC en red?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

me he creado un contenedor en mi NAS que soportar docker, luego he hecho un `docker ps`, como resultado obtengo mi docker creado con sus  datos :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
62d5f076c9d9        php                 "docker-php-entryp..."   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:32397->1515/tcp   php_test
```

Como podeis observar el nombre del  docker es **test_ptp**, ahora bien, me gustaria acceder desde mi pc, ajeno a mi nas para que me saliera el index.html que he creado en el contenedor, pero no me deja.

¿Que tendria que hacer o que estoy haciendo mal?

La ip de mi NAS es : 123 (ejemplo).

Pues segun lo que dice la lista de mis contenedores se  supone que poniendo : **123:32397** deberia salir mi index, no ? Pues no sale

Comment: Habría que ver primero que no haya ningún problema en el contenedor. Por qué 1515? Podrías compartir tu Dockerfile, aunque elimines cualquier dato sensible?

Answer (score 0):

El servicio probablemente será accesible si te conectas al NAS por ssh e intentas conectarte localmente al puerto 32397 (i.e: 127.0.0.1:32397), por ejemplo con CURL o wget.

Para poder conectar desde fuera necesitas o bien re-configurar docker para que utilice otro interfaz de red que no sea el local (no es la mejor solución), o bien instalar un software que te permita configurar un reverse proxy, como NGinx o HAproxy. En NAS como los de Synology esto no debería ser un problema.

Answer (score 0):

En primer paso tenes que asegurarte de que el port-forwarding que estas haciendo al levantar el contenedor sea correcto, adentro del contenedor, **tu index.html sale por el puerto 1515?**.
Luego tenes que asegurarte de que el puerto 32397 de tu servidor NAS no esté bloqueado por ningun firewall, y se pueda llegar a el sin problemas, te sugiero pegarle con este comando:

```
telnet tuip tupuerto
```

Asegurate que la pc desde donde intentas ingresar comparte la misma red.